# Python tkinter unique button text variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I'm trying to create a grid of 9 buttons that, when pressed, will display their number. However I'm having issues, when I press a single button, I end up setting all of their text variables to the same number. How can I create a unique `textvariable` for each button?

Code:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

# Initialise items
num = 0
buttons = []
buttons_string = StringVar()


# My button function
def buttons_selection(a):
    print(a)
    buttons[a][1].set(a)


# Buttons is a 2d list where I store the button and it's text variable in
for i in range(9):
    buttons.append([])
    buttons[i].append(0)
    buttons[i].append(buttons_string)

# These for loops create the buttons
for x in range(3):
    for y in range(3):

        buttons[num][0] = Button(root, command=lambda a=num: buttons_selection(a),
                                 textvariable=buttons[num][1],  height=2, width=5) .grid(row=y, column=x)
        num += 1

root.mainloop()
```

To help clarify a bit more, this particular line is the issue:

```py
buttons[num][0] = Button(root, command=lambda a=num: buttons_selection(a),
                                 textvariable=buttons[num][1],  height=2, width=5) .grid(row=y, column=x)
```

I want to make it so that the `textvariable=buttons[num][1]` unique variable is stored in the button or something.

Comment: You used same `StringVar` (`buttons_string`) for all the buttons.  Change `buttons[i].append(buttons_string)` to `buttons[i].append(StringVar())`.

Comment: Doing the processes inside multiple `functions` will help.

Comment: Oh, thanks @acw1668 . I thought I had already tried that and got a syntax error, must have done a typo or something.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the suggestion that acw1668 worked. Simply appending a new string variable worked fine

```py
buttons[i].append(StringVar())
```